# Javascript to select all but the first checkbox on a page?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to be able to automatically mark all the checkboxes on a page EXCEPT the first one.

I have found a javascript snippet that selects all the checkboxes, that is currently working for that purpose, but I don't want it to select the first checkbox...

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function (el) {el.checked = true});
```

I've tried various If statements within the above snippet, all of which break the process.

Any help will be appreciated.  Note:(I am implementing this as a bookmarklet.)

Comment: Just set them all then after reset the first one to not checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback function can take a second parameter that is the `index`.  So add a condition that `index !== 0`, that is `function (el, index) { if (index !== 0) { el.checked = true; } }`.

Or even `function (el, index) { el.checked = index !== 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

You could change your query selector to add `:not(:first-child)`

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:first-child)'), function (el) {el.checked = true});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLhhyy7m/2/

Or with jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:first)').attr("checked",true);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLhhyy7m/1/

Comment: `:first` =/= `:first-child`

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i) {
    if (i)
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
}
```